# $R$ Noetherian $\implies$ Every finitely generated $R$-module is Noetherian

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, proof-explanation

I'm trying to study a little modules theory from my professor notes (no book has been given) and I'm really struggling.

> Given a $R$-module $M$, $N \le M$, define: $$d_R(N) = \min (\{ n \in \mathbb{N} : \exists m_1,\dots, m_n \ \langle m_1,\dots,m_n \rangle =
> N \} \cup \{ \infty \})$$

I didn't find this definition elsewhere, I'm not too sure it is well posed.

The proof uses this lemma (whose proof is clear to me).

> **Lemma**. $\quad d_R(M) \le d_R(N) + d_R(M/N)$

$\quad$

> **Proposition**. $ \quad R$ Noetherian $\iff$ every finitely generated $R$-module is Noetherian
>
> **Proof:** ($\Longleftarrow$) is clear.
>
> ($\implies$) Let $n = d_R(M)$. If $n=1$, $M = Rm$ and $\phi_m: R \to
> M, r \mapsto rm$ is an epimorphism. So $I_N =\phi_m^{-1}(N)$ is a
>   finitely generated ideal by hypothesis. We have $N \simeq I_N/\ker
> \phi_m$, so, by the lemma, $d_R(N) \le d_R(I_N)$ ...

I've problems with that "so". I don't understand how the lemma is being used.
I understood the rest of the proof, but I appreciate if you can go through it to verify.

> ... $N$ is finitely generated and thus $M$ is noetherian.
>   Suppose now that the claim is valid for $n$, let's prove it is valid for $n+1$. Let $M = \sum_{i=0}^n Rm_i$ and $M_0 = Rm_0$. Note that $M = M_0 + \sum_{i=1}^n Rm_i$. $M/M_0 = \sum_{i=1}^n R(m + M_0)$ and so $d_R(M/M_0) \le n$. 
>   Let $N \le M$, then by the lemma:
>   $$ d_R(N) \le d_R(N/(N\cap M_0)) + d_R(N\cap M_0)$$
>   Since $N \cap M_0 \le M_0$, $d_R(N \cap M_0) < \infty$. By the isomorphism theorems $N/(N\cap M_0) \simeq (N + M_0) / M_0 \le M/M_0$. Since $M/M_0$ is noetherian by induction hypothesis, $(N+M_0)/M_0$, and hence $N$ is finitely generated. $\square$.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lemma is not used in the first part. In the case $n=1$, it simply relies on the fact that $N$ being (isomorphic to) a quotient of an ideal of $R$, it has a finite set of generators.

For the inductive step, uses the *second isomorphism theorem* and the lemma. Besides, I corrected typos in some formulae  which made the proof hard to read.

Comment: Thanks. I'm sorry for typos.